# Multiple Queries one PHP script

Tags: php, mysql

I have a page called profile.php I need information from multiple tables from within the same database.

Are multiple queries the way to deal with this, like this:

```
//connect

//query1
//query2
//query3
//query4

Mysqli_Query(connect, query1)
Mysqli_Query(connect, query2)
Mysqli_Query(connect, query3)
Mysqli_Query(connect, query4)
```

Comment: "Probably, but it must not while it could be."

Comment: Unless you give us specifics, yes.

Comment: You can run multiple queries, but that doesn't mean you should. If the data is all related, it may be best to write far fewer (maybe only one) query that joins the data together. Without further info, we cannot help.

Comment: Why is there this generalized fear of running multiple queries within a script? It's like people are afraid to buy more than 1 thing at a store at a time.

Answer (score 0):

There is certainly nothing stopping you from making multiple queries, but depending on what you're doing, a JOIN is likely far more appropriate.

There's more to cover here than can reasonably fit in a StackOverflow answer, so please try a tutorial:  http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqljoins.php

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're gathering data from `query1` and using it in `query2` and so on, you can optimize multiple queries into a single query by using [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) or [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html). That's all I can offer without seeing any actual code.

Answer (score 0):

what i get from your question is that there are many tables and you just need information from them, in that case it is better to go for UNION or JOIN over multiple queries as long as the tables are somehow related.